# Best practices to grow haskap bush: Lonicera caerulea edulis

Tags: shrubs, fruits, honeysuckle

This [honeysuckle with edible fruit](http://albertafruittrees.tripod.com/id8.html) is being sold by retailers in my area as the new best thing.  After researching them I planted three varieties to get good cross pollination.

- What experience have people had growing them?
- Do they perform as advertised:  seedless large berries that ripen ahead of most other fruit shrubs?
- any pest or disease problems?
- how many varieties do you need for good fruit set?  The literature is confusing on this issue.

Edit: we have only ever seen one deer in seven years and it was confused so I can't tell if these honeysuckle are a tasty treat for them. Right now they are just snack size.

Comment: Looks interesting. Let us know how it goes. Do you have to deal with deer? I'm interested in anything that won't be bothered by deer...

Comment: We planted a few this winter, can't remember what variety of the top of my head. I'll be interested to hear what people say.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deer don't seem to be an issue with Haskap.  I had a Hosta and a haskap side by side and the the deer took the hosta and didn't touch the Haskap.

On our farm as well, there were no issues with deer an the Haskap.

Answer (score 4):

The only pest we've noticed so far is the [Forest Tent Caterpillar](http://www.haskapusa.blogspot.ca/2012/06/zone-3-forest-tent-caterpillars-dine-on.html). The deer nibbled a bit on fresh growth but did not ravage the young plants like they did the cherries.